# Swift stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, swift, uiwebview

I try to use some javascript on my WebView with the new

`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` function

I m not quiet familiar with the syntax so i tried

```
 func stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString( "document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none'": String) -> String?
```

as shown here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: but i get a error that "Expected '.' separator"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method you are trying to call is prototyped as the following:

`func stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_ script: String) -> String?`

This means :

- It takes a `String` as single parameter
- It returns an optional `String` (`String?`)

You need to have an instance of `UIWebView` to use it:

```
let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none'")
```

Because the return type is [optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485), it needs to be unwrapped before you can use it.
But be careful, it may not have a value (i.e. it may be equal to `nil`) and unwrapping nil values leads to runtime crashes.

So you need to check for that before you can use the returned string:

```
if let returnedString = result {
    println("the result is \(returnedString)")
}
```

This means: If `result` is not `nil` then unwrap it and assign it to a new constant called `returnedString`.

Additionally, you can wrap it together with:

```
let script = "document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none'"
if let returnedString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(script) {
    println("the result is \(returnedString)")
}
```

Hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to call the javascript script directly from uiwebview

```
let htmlTitle = myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title");
println(htmlTitle)
```

http://sourcefreeze.com/uiwebview-example-using-swift-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

1) Create JavaScript constant:

```
let jsString: String = "document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none'"
```

2) Using [evaluateJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) function for [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) (iOS 8.0+)

```
self?.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("", completionHandler: { result, error in
       print(result)
})
```

or [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617963-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfrom) for [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) (iOS 2.0–12.0)

```
let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsString)
print(result)
```

Also from Apple doc:

> The stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method waits synchronously
>   for JavaScript evaluation to complete. 
>   If you load web content whose
>   JavaScript code you have not vetted, invoking this method could hang
>   your app. Best practice is to adopt the WKWebView class and use its
>   evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler: method instead.