# Swift & UIWebView element to hide

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, uiwebview

I got a UIWebView and I load the content like that

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.myresponsivesite.fr/section/");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

It's working perfectly but I would like to put some div and other elements in display none. So my question is : How can I inject some css from my app with swift?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found another way, I load my html in a variable and, i replace some div with a "display:none" exemple :

```
 let urlDeBase = "http://mywebsite/section/"    
    if let url = NSURL (string: urlDeBase){
        var error: NSError?
        let myHTML = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

and I replace what i want

```
 let mystring = myHTML?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<h3 class=\"myclass\">Menu</h3>", withString: "<h3 class=\"myclass\" style=\"display:none\">Menu</h3>")
 webvieww.loadHTMLString(mystring, baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple post on it and the Apple docs, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434268/injecting-a-new-stylesheet-into-a-website-via-uiwebview-using-ios8-swift-xcode-6) was one solution:

> So, I think I found at least one way to accomplish appending styles to the webpage being loaded using Swift:

```
var loadStyles = "var script = 
  document.createElement('link');
  script.type = 'text/css';
  script.rel = 'stylesheet';
  script.href = 'http://fake-url/styles.css';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);"
```

`website.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadStyles)`

Here is the other post: [Swift stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056132/swift-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring)

Then the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/mediaStyle).

Comment: If I understood, the var is going to create a css file, so if i add one more line in the var just like : "script.text = #myId { display : none; }" is it good ?

Comment: I can't really say, I don't have any experience with it. You will have to mess around with it. I tried to find information on how it works exactly but I couldn't find any.