# how to load local html file to string variable in ios swift?

Tags: html, ios, string, swift, uiwebview

i want to load my local html file into a string variable. i don't know how to do it. please help me. 
i found below link but it load it from online url.
[Swift & UIWebView element to hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355912/swift-uiwebview-element-to-hide)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Copy the html into your project directory and use this code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        var htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyHtmlFile", ofType: "html")
        var htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: nil)


}
```

Comment: I'm quite confused. Where is the exact path defined? I'm a newbie in swift and also in xcode:/ However I cannot figure out... maybe: How to load the file in xcode project to target it this way?

Comment: @ Tomas Javurek just drag your file inside the project folder

Comment: @RizwanShaikh I did it this way, intuitively. I already have 'default.html' in my xcode project and I try to load it this way `let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "html")`. The file is also a part of compiled bundle and is in Resources folder. But while I try to get the content of file, it produce an error. I tried also print the value of htmlFile, unwrapped, and it returns `nil`..., so my problem is somewhere else... any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I figure it out by using this code: `let bundle = Bundle(for: MyView.self)
        let url = bundle.url(forResource:"default", withExtension:"html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.load(request)`

Comment: @TomasJavurek, you are my hero.  You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift 3:**

```
    let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"MyHtmlFile", ofType: "html")
    let htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: nil)
```

I recommend using [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) instead of force unwrapping `htmlString` as above.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some utility method like this and get the html string and load it to webview. I used the URL approach here

```
   private func getHTML() -> String {
        var html = ""
        if let htmlPathURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "html"){
            do {
                html = try String(contentsOf: htmlPathURL, encoding: .utf8)
            } catch  {
                print("Unable to get the file.")
            }
        }

        return html
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 syntax:

```
    guard
        let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "agreement", ofType: "html"), 
        let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    else {
        return
    }
    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Simple answer**

```
 let indexPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "/")
        if let indexPath = indexPath
        {
            do
            {
                let htmlContent = try String(contentsOfFile: indexPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                let base = Bundle.main.resourceURL 
                self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: base)

            }
            catch let err as NSError
            {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
        }
```